# Ajax.BeginForm doesn't post properly

Tags: ajax, asp.net-mvc-3, post, razor

I have a simple requirement I seem unable to meet: I have a product page.  products have vendors and the vendor input is a text field with an autocomplete.  if the user enters a vendor that doesn't exist in the database, I need to add it.  to add it I have a DIV on the page which I .load() with a call to my /Vendor/Create controller method.  the view for that method uses:

```
@using (Ajax.BeginForm("Create", "Vendor", new AjaxOptions {
     UpdateTargetId = ViewBag.TargetId,
     HttpMethod = "Post", 
     OnSuccess="VendorCreated", 
     OnComplete="alert('success')"
})) {
```

which should post my form via ajax, calling Javascript when done.  The problem I'm having is that upon submission my whole page gets refreshed such that I end up with /Vendor/Create when I started with /Product/Create.  additionally, neither the OnSuccess nor OnComplete get called.

what am I doing wrong here?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Make sure you have included the following scripts to your page:

```
jquery-1.5.1.js
jquery.unobtrusive-ajax.js
```

and that unobtrusive javascript is enabled in web.config:

```
<add key="UnobtrusiveJavaScriptEnabled" value="true" />
```

Comment: oh... I see.  my project has -1.4.4 and I don't have a jquery.unobtrusive-ajax.js but I do have a MicrosoftAjax.js and MicrosoftMvcAjax.js... are they the same thing?

Comment: I've looked at both files but neither contains a BeginForm... a related question: I've read that using a CDN is a good thing but that means not having the script in the Scripts folders.  is there a way to just make a reference so the scripts look like they're in your project but they really just grab from the CDN?

Comment: @ekkis, you can safely remove `MicrosoftAjax.js` and `MicrosoftMvcAjax.js` from your ASP.NET MVC 3 project. By default ASP.NET MVC 3 uses jQuery. So leave only the two scripts I have mentioned in my answer (you could replace jquery-1.5.1.js with the version you are actually using) and enable unobtrusive javascript in web.config.