# Browser display json response from ActionResult on Azure Web app, but not on localhost

Tags: json, asp.net-mvc, azure

I am posting data to an Action, get json data as a result, and then, process the result in javascript.

It's work well on dev server, but when i publish it on Azure WebApp, when I post my data, it display the json on the screen.

The begining of my Form to post data :

```
@using (Ajax.BeginForm("UpdateAccount", "Loging",
new AjaxOptions
{
    HttpMethod = "POST",
    OnSuccess = "processAccountUpdateResult"
}))
{
```

Note: *processAccountUpdateResult* is the javascript function which process the json result.

Here is my action :

```
[HttpPost]
public ActionResult UpdateAccount(string newName)
{
    return Json(new { result = "ok" }, "text/html", JsonRequestBehavior.AllowGet);
}
```

Note : I added the "text/html" mime type after I [read this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/8591998/ie-tries-to-download-json-in-asp-net-mvc-3)
But no luck.
I tried to add the json mimetype in the web.config, but still no luck :

```
<configuration>
  <system.webServer>
    <staticContent>
      <mimeMap fileExtension=".json" mimeType="application/json"/>
    </staticContent>
  </system.webServer>
</configuration>
```

Thanks

Comment: See this answer http://stackoverflow.com/questions/5904117/ajax-beginform-doesnt-post-properly

Comment: Thanks. Adding '<add key="UnobtrusiveJavaScriptEnabled" value="true" />' makes it working. But i had to remove json file extension from the System.webServer configuration.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

To make it working, we need to add this to the web.config :

```
<add key="UnobtrusiveJavaScriptEnabled" value="true" />
```