# Browser returns json when it should redirect

Tags: asp.net-mvc, aspnetboilerplate

Using ABP, I've created a project and when i try to log in, my browser returns the json values rather than redirecting me.

Closet question i found was [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/31210737/browser-display-json-response-from-actionresult-on-azure-web-app-but-not-on-loc) but the selected answer made no difference on my end.

Comment: check this out as it has great advicse that will help you get the help you need: 
 https://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask

Answer (score 0, accepted):

yarn & npm run create-bundles