# Ajax call in MVC3 not working

Tags: asp.net-mvc

I am unable to make an Ajax call via below code snippet. If I remove the AJAX call - it works perfectly fine only problem is form is posted back to server.
**Please let me know what I am missing or doing wrong in implementing Ajax call...**

> Error:
>   The resource cannot be found.
>   404 Page not found.
>   Requested URL: /Home/GetEmp

Controller
 -- This is common method that I am calling for first time when user clicks on Employee to get all employees.
-- When user enters some criteira... this method is again invoked with search criteria that user enters.
-- If I remove the AJAX call - it works perfectly fine only problem is form is posted back to server.

```
[HttpGet]
public ActionResult GetEmp(string strSearchCriteria = null)
{
    obj = new EmpRepository();
    var model = obj.GetAllEmployees()
        .Where(e => strSearchCriteria == null || e.EmpName.StartsWith(strSearchCriteria))
        .Select(e => new EMP
        {
            EmpID = e.EmpID,
            EmpName = e.EmpName
        });
    if (Request.IsAjaxRequest())
    {
        return PartialView("EmpPartial", model);
    }
    return View(model);
}
```

GetEmp View
-- this is my ajax call

```
@using (Ajax.BeginForm("GetEmp", "Home", new AjaxOptions { HttpMethod = "get", InsertionMode = InsertionMode.Replace, UpdateTargetId = "UpdateEmpList" }))
{
    <input type="text" name="strSearchCriteria"/>
    <input type="submit" value="Search by name" />
}
```

-- this is partial view (given details below) I am calling
   @Html.Partial("EmpPartial", Model)

EmpPartial view
-- Partial view.

```
@model IEnumerable<abc.Models.EMP>
<div id="UpdateEmpList">
    @foreach (var item in Model)
    {
        <tr>
            <td>
                @Html.DisplayFor(modelItem => item.EmpName)
            </td>
            <td>
                @Html.ActionLink("Edit", "Edit", new { id = item.EmpID }) |
                @Html.ActionLink("Details", "Details", new { id = item.EmpID }) |
                @Html.ActionLink("Delete", "Delete", new { id = item.EmpID })
            </td>
        </tr>
    }
</div>
```

Comment: Your method is marked `[HttpGet]` so it should be ``new AjaxOptions { HttpMethod = "get" ..``

Comment: Thank you for quick update here... but it is actually get..  I was trying some options and forgot to remove post from ajax call.           @using (Ajax.BeginForm("GetEmp", "Home", new AjaxOptions { HttpMethod = "get", InsertionMode = InsertionMode.Replace, UpdateTargetId = "UpdateEmpList" }))
    {
        <input type="text" name="strSearchCriteria" />
        <input type="submit" value="Search by name" />
      
    }

Comment: few things you have to have to make this work right and not just post back..  check the answer here http://stackoverflow.com/questions/5904117/ajax-beginform-doesnt-post-properly

Comment: Are you saying this works if you use `Html.BeginForm` instead of `Ajax.BeginForm`?

Comment: What I meant here is - if I remove the ajax call then request works fine.  I am using  below code  in getEmp view <form method="get">
     <input type="text" name="strSearchCriteria" />
     <input type="submit" value="Search by name" />
    </form>   and then calling partial view       -->    @Html.Partial("EmpPartial", Model)

Comment: Like @JamieD77 said above ... the Ajax.BeginForm helper has a dependency on jquery.unobstrusive.js library, do you have that library referenced in your project? I was able to reproduce your problem and solve it just by adding a reference to the unobstrusive library.

Comment: :) Solved... Thank you very much